# React Native - Touchable and Victory Chart

Tags: javascript, events, react-native, touchableopacity, victory-charts

How do I prevent the press event from being intercepted by the Victory Chart and instead 'click through' to the touchable parent? Essentially I want to be able to click anywhere on the chart and go to the detail view. Eventually there will be other elements inside the touchableOpacity element so I do not want to capture the press on the chart directly.

I apologize for the poor wording, I'm very new to React and React Native.

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.panel}
    onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
    <VictoryChart>
      <VictoryBar
        style={{
          data: {fill: "blue"}
        }}
        data={data}
        x="quarter"
        y="earnings"
      />
    </VictoryChart>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538736/5563513). Adding the `containerComponent` prop, as described in the link, to your VictoryChart component will call the `onPress` function in TouchableOpacity when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought of another approach. Try adding a second, invisible view after the VictoryChart. I'll call it InvisibleView. Stick both the VictoryChart and InvisibleView in a parent view, making the InvisibleView touchable like this...

```
const InvisibleView = () => <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} />/

<View>
    <VictoryChart ...>
    <TouchableOpacity...>
        <InvisibleView />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: I actually added a new VictoryBar over my complex chart and it allowed me to catch events for the whole group reliably. Great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `events` prop? [Read about it here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-props/#events)

The docs show this example...

```
events={[{
    childName: "all",
    target: "data",
    eventHandlers: {
      onClick: () => {
        return [
          {
            childName: "area-2",
            target: "data",
            mutation: (props) => ({ style: Object.assign({}, props.style, { fill: "gold" }) })
          }, {
            childName: "area-3",
            target: "data",
            mutation: (props) => ({ style: Object.assign({}, props.style, { fill: "orange" }) })
          }, {
            childName: "area-4",
            target: "data",
            mutation: (props) => ({ style: Object.assign({}, props.style, { fill: "red" }) })
          }
        ];
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

This shows an `onClick` handler which is used to mutate the actual data, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't use it to navigate to the details screen. I'm not certain of the syntax you'll need.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for. The events prop lets me intercept a touch on the chart, however I eventually plan on having more elements besides just the chart inside my touchable so I'm looking for away to capture the event at that level.