# victory-native : events props not working in react native / event not firing in react native when using victory bar chart

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I am trying to implement Victor bar chart in which I want to perform some action when user click on the bar. but when do so using event props which in given in the docs(using the same sample code given in [docs](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/events/#single-component-events)) but the event is not firing.
You can also see my implementation on snack.expo.io using this link...[ClickMe](https://snack.expo.io/@rajatgng/victoryevent)

package version are:

```
"react-native-svg": "^9.4.0",
"victory-native": "^32.0.2",
"expo": "^33.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
```

here is same code for your reference...

**Note :** **I also used 'onPressIn', 'onClick' and 'onPress' neither of them work.**

```
<VictoryBar
   data={[
     {x: 1, y: 2, label: "A"},
     {x: 2, y: 4, label: "B"},
     {x: 3, y: 7, label: "C"},
     {x: 4, y: 3, label: "D"},
     {x: 5, y: 5, label: "E"},
   ]}
   events={[
     {
       target: "data",
       eventHandlers: {
         onPressIn: () => {
           return [{
             target: "labels",
             mutation: (props) => {
               return props.text === "clicked" ?
                 null : { text: "clicked" }
             }
           }];
         }
       }
     }
   ]}
 />
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping it in `Svg` like this worked for me:

```
<Svg>
  <VictoryPie
    height={280}
    colorScale={pie_chart_color}
    data={this.state.data}
    style={...}
    events={[...]}
  />
</Svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try wrapping the VictoryBar inside the VictoryChart. And the VictoryChart inside TouchableOpacity like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={...}>
    <VictoryChart containerComponent={<VictoryContainer disableContainerEvents />}
   ...>
       <VictoryBar
        ... />
    </VictoryChart>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do this with a word, the event will behave as normal as a document.

```js
<VictoryBar
  data={[
    {x: 1, y: 2, label: "A"},
    {x: 2, y: 4, label: "B"},
    {x: 3, y: 7, label: "C"},
    {x: 4, y: 3, label: "D"},
    {x: 5, y: 5, label: "E"},
  ]}
  events={[{
    target: "data",
    eventHandlers: {
      onPress: () => {
        return [
          {
            mutation: (props) => {
              return props.text === "clicked" ?
                null : { text: "clicked" }
            }
          }
        ];
      }
    }
  }]}
/>
```

Comment: I tried it through a snack. Would you like to run the code through the snack?

Answer (score 1):

In my case wrapping charts with TouchableOpacity works only with ios and wrapping with svg works with android. So i just had to switch the wrapper according to platform ,

```
const ChartClick=Platform.select({
  ios: TouchableOpacity,
  android: Svg
});
```

And I use this as ,

```
<ChartClick>
 <VictoryChart>
 </VictoryChart>
</ChartClick>
```

My package versions are : react-native-svg:9.0.0,victory-native:34.0.0

Answer (score 1):

To keep the content up to date, on Android you can set "onPressIn" instead of "onPress" so that the event is acknowledged.

```
<VictoryChart
  containerComponent={<VictoryContainer disableContainerEvents />}
>
  <VictoryBar
    events={[{
      target: 'data',
      eventHandlers: {
        onPressIn: () => console.log('Pressed!')
      }
    }]}
  />
</VictoryChart>
```